# Using Stripe Elements to create a subscription with a free trial period isn't saving the payment method to the customer

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, payment

I'm migrating from Payment Links to a direct PaymentElement integration

Here is my flow:

1. Create Customer and Subscription/PaymentIntent/PendingSetupIntent on server
2. Render PaymentElement using the pending SetupIntent on the client-side
3. Customer enters payment info and clicks submit
4. Call confirmSetup on the client-side

This successfully creates the customer and subscription, but the payment method that the customer provided isn't attached, so payments are failing after the trial period ends. There is no payment method associated with the Customer.

I want the payment method that they entered to be associated with their account so that the payments succeed after the trial period ends.

Here is my code:

1. Create Customer and PaymentIntent/PendingSetupIntent on server

```
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
      phone: phone_number,
      email: email,
      metadata: {

      }
    });
    const customer_id = customer['id'];

    try {
      const paymentIntent = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
        customer: customer_id,
        items: [{
          price: PRICE_ID,
        }],
        payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete',
        payment_settings: { save_default_payment_method: 'on_subscription' },
        trial_period_days: 7,
        expand: ["pending_setup_intent"],
      });
      const pending_setup_intent = paymentIntent.pending_setup_intent as Stripe.SetupIntent;

      res.status(200).json({
        paymentIntent: pending_setup_intent.id,
        clientSecret: pending_setup_intent.client_secret,
      })
      return
```

2. Render PaymentElement using the PendingSetupIntent on the client-side

```
       function mountStripePaymentElement(stripeCustomerUnconfirmedSubscriptionPayment) {

            const options = {
              clientSecret: stripeCustomerUnconfirmedSubscriptionPayment.clientSecret,
              appearance: {
                labels: 'floating'
              },
              loader: 'always'
            };


            const stripe = Stripe(STRIPE_PK_LIVE);
            const elements = stripe.elements(options);

            // Create and mount the Payment Element
            const paymentElement = elements.create('payment');        
            paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');

            const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
            form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
              event.preventDefault();

              const {error} = await stripe.confirmSetup({
                //`Elements` instance that was used to create the Payment Element
                elements,
                confirmParams: {
                  return_url: "https://mywebsite.com/welcome",
                },
                maxNetworkRetries: 5,
                timeout: 1000,
                telemetry: false
              });

              if (error) {
                // This point will only be reached if there is an immediate error when
                // confirming the payment. Show error to your customer (for example, payment
                // details incomplete)
                const messageContainer = document.querySelector('#error-message');
                messageContainer.textContent = error.message;
              } else {
                // Your customer will be redirected to your `return_url`. For some payment
                // methods like iDEAL, your customer will be redirected to an intermediate
                // site first to authorize the payment, then redirected to the `return_url`.
              }
            });
        }
```

3+4: See the confirmSetup request in the above

Thank you

Comment: With [`payment_settings.save_default_payment_method: 'on_subscription'`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-payment_settings-save_default_payment_method), the payment method will be saved under [`subscription.default_payment_method`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-default_payment_method) in subscription object. Any invoices for this subscription will be paid with `subscription.default_payment_method`. It's expected that the payment method is not saved under customer object.

Comment: When you mentioned about payment failure, what exactly the failure reason is? A payment failure can be many reasons such as insufficient funds on the card and it has nothing to do payment method not saved.

Comment: @yuting  thank you for your quick replies

I don't see a payment method saved on the subscription object either 

eg on https://dashboard.stripe.com/subscriptions/sub_1Ly2VmDLMHmEgGmV6AuvDAuO it says "Billing method: Charge default payment method"

I don't see a failure reason on the payment failure events. I don't think it's an insufficient funds kind of thing because all 6 of the customers whose trials have completed since launch have failed payments

Thank you for your help please let me know if I can provide any more info to help diagnose

Comment: If `stripe.confirmSetup` on the subscription setup intent is successful, you should receive `customer.subscription.updated` with payment method ID (pm_xxx) under [`subscription.default_payment_method`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-default_payment_method). If you [retrieve the Subscription]()https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve, `default_payment_method` should be present as well. In addition, successful setup intent will also receive `setup_intent.succeeded` event.

Comment: You can check whether the setup intent has saved successfully with: https://dashboard.stripe.com/setup_intents/{setup_intent_id}

Comment: Thank you @yuting

I see successful setup intents with payment ids, eg:

https://pastebin.com/cx29NQRj

And some that don't have the payment method

https://pastebin.com/PYxDQzBN

Comment: In the screenshot you shared, the status is in `requires_payment_method` not `succeeded`, so the SetupIntent does not collect payment method successfully. This is the [lifecycle of a SetupIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/intents?intent=setup).